# Invoke ActiveX In Electron

Tags: activex, electron

I have several activex controls( .cab files) for DSVerify Or DigitalSignature and in the past i use html and load them into ie like:

`DigitalSign.GetSelCertSign();

...
<object id="DigitalSign" codeBase="DigitalSign.NJGGZY.x86.cab#version=3,0,0,1" classid="clsid:AE9C27E1-AF18-48A6-8087-026064B130D5"></object>`

and now  i want to use electron as cross-platform runtime, but i don't know how to invoke these activex plugins in electron , or how to embeded ie in electron?

Comment: In addition to [Paul Betts' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36314844/111794), ActiveX technology is really only a Windows technology, and is thus irrelevant to electron, which is cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, sorry! Electron is based on Chrome, which doesn't support ActiveX

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveX Objects can be invoked with some npm packages, like "win32ole". You can see a few examples here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole