# how to support activeX control in an app created with Node.js and angular5

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, internet-explorer-11, activex

I want to create a standalone app which is created with node.js and angular5. this app is using activexobject. I want to enable ActiveX in a standalone app.

I went through several recommendations for creating standalone app created with node.js. I tried appjs. but there I am getting an error 'ActiveX control failed to load. Please check browser security settings!'.

I used this library:

https://github.com/appjs/appjs

I can't use Electron, because it is based on chrome which doesn't support ActiveX. I found this on below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36314844/3366119

```
var app = module.exports = require('appjs');

app.serveFilesFrom(__dirname + '/Source/dist');

var menubar = app.createMenu([{
  label:'&File',
  submenu:[
    {
      label:'E&xit',
      action: function(){
        window.close();
      }
    }
  ]
},{
  label:'&Window',
    submenu:[
    {
      label:'Fullscreen',
      action:function(item) {
        window.frame.fullscreen();
        console.log(item.label+" called.");
      }
    },
    {
      label:'Minimize',
      action:function(){
        window.frame.minimize();
      }
    },
    {
      label:'Maximize',
      action:function(){
        window.frame.maximize();
      }
    },{
      label:''//separator
    },{
      label:'Restore',
      action:function(){
        window.frame.restore();
      }
    }
  ]
 }]);

menubar.on('select',function(item){
  console.log("menu item "+item.label+" clicked");
});

var trayMenu = app.createMenu([{
  label:'Show',
  action:function(){
    window.frame.show();
  },
},{
  label:'Minimize',
  action:function(){
    window.frame.hide();
  }
},{
  label:'Exit',
  action:function(){
    window.close();
  }
}]);

var statusIcon = app.createStatusIcon({
  icon:'./data/content/icons/32.png',
  tooltip:'AppJS Hello World',
  menu:trayMenu
});

var window = app.createWindow({
  width  : 800,
  height : 600,
  icons  : __dirname + '/content/icons'
 });

window.on('create', function(){
  console.log("Window Created");
  window.frame.show();
  window.frame.center();
  window.frame.setMenuBar(menubar);
});

window.on('ready', function(){
  console.log("Window Ready");
  window.process = process;
  window.module = module;

   function F12(e){ return e.keyIdentifier === 'F12' }
  function Command_Option_J(e){ return e.keyCode === 74 && e.metaKey && 
  e.altKey }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
     if (F12(e) || Command_Option_J(e)) {
      window.frame.openDevTools();
    }
  });
});

window.on('close', function(){
  console.log("Window Closed");
});
```

I want to create a standalone app created with Node.js and angular5 with ActiveX support. any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to refer to [this article](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/remote-control-enable-activex.html) to set the Internet browser security settings and enable ActiveX in IE browser. Here are two threads with the same error, you could refer to them: [link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2701da57-08b4-4baf-8316-793b370c0e7c/active-x-control-failed-to-load?forum=ieitprocurrentver) and [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b5a7941-f6e0-44fd-b7e7-82052ec77e0c/activex-control-failed-to-load?forum=vststest). Besides, if you want to use Activex in chrome, you could use [IE Tab extension](https://itstillworks.com/enable-activex-google-chrome-9756.html).